# Linked sheets shift formula values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets in Google Sheets that are linked.

**Sheet1** is the 'root source'.(Sheet1 is a Google Form sheet that automatically updates with new responses).

**Sheet2** uses the formula "=Sheet1!C2" to transfer values from Sheet1 to a specific column (in Sheet2).
The formula in Sheet2 is expanded/copied so that "=Sheet1!C2" is followed by "=Sheet1!C3", "=Sheet1!C4", and so on.

**The problem**: Every time a new entry in Sheet1 is created (i.e. a new response is created), Sheet2 does not get a new entry (but it should since I have defined it using the mentioned formulas). When inspecting the formula, I see that cell in the formula (like C3, C4, ...) gets shifted upwards by 1.
Therefore, the cell (still in Sheet2) that was defined with the formula "=Sheet1!C3" is automatically changed to "=Sheet1!C4".

How can I prevent this automatic upwards shifting of the formula when a new response/entry is created in Sheet1 (so that it automatically arrives in Sheet2 as well)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use arrayformula in row 1 in your Sheet2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"header"; Sheet1!C2:C})
```

Comment: It throws an error (#REF!: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C4")..

Comment: @2stefan2000 you need to delete everything in range C2:C. only then the formula will be able to roll out and autopopulate all rows